# Xamarin-Threading AudioTrack

Tags: c#, xamarin, signal-processing

I am trying to generate white noise on a sinewave but there is a pause in my signal that should not be there.I am not sure why.
I have the write function on a different thread than generator.
here  is my code:

```
public class whitenoise :AudioTrack 
{
    public whitenoise (int min1) : base(Stream.Music,44100, ChannelOut.Stereo,         Encoding.Pcm16bit,793800,AudioTrackMode.Stream)
    {

        Frequency = 1000;
        Amplitude = 1;
        n2 = 0;
        min = min1;
        buffer = new short[793800];
    }
    public double Frequency { get; set; }
    public double Amplitude { get; set; }
    static int stopped;
    static int n2;
    int min;
    short[] buffer;
    Random rnd1;
    void write1()
    {
        while(n2 < min )
        {
            Write (buffer, 0,793800);
        }
    }

    public void play()
    {
    rnd1 = new System.Random();
        stopped = 0;
    gen(buffer);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>write1());

        Play();
        while (n2 < min) 
        {
            gen (buffer);
            //Write (buffer, 0, 793800);
        }
        stopped = 1; 
    }


     public void gen(short[] buffer)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n <793800; n++) {
            if (Frequency == 0) {
                float temp1 = (float)(Amplitude * (2 * rnd1.NextDouble () - 1));
                buffer [n] = (short)(temp1 * short.MaxValue);
            } else {
                float w = (float)( Math.Sin ( n2 * Math.PI * Frequency / 44100D));
                float temp1 = (float)(w * Amplitude * (2 * rnd1.NextDouble () - 1));
                buffer [n] = (short)(temp1 * short.MaxValue);
            }

               n2++;
        }
    }

    public void stop ()
    {
        n2 = (min);
        stopped = 1;
    }

    public int getstopped()
    {
        return stopped;
    } 
}
```

why is it not working?
why is there a pause ?
the  gen is making the signal on a different thread
and  both functions can use  the buffer array

UPDate :

ok so while I was troubleshooting this problem, I learned that write() is called like 4 to 3 more times than gen(). SO, I need to make gen faster, I tried lowering the buffer size  and I learned the loses I can go is without having problems in the sound is 44100, but gen is still too slow. so I tried this :

```
public void gen(short[] buffer)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n <44100; n++) {
                if (Frequency == 0) {
                    float temp1 = (float)(Amplitude * (2 * rnd1.NextDouble () - 1));
                    buffer [n] = (short)(temp1 * short.MaxValue);
                } else {
                float temp1 = (float)( Math.Sin ( n2 * SinMath) * Amplitude * (2 * rnd1.NextDouble () - 1));
                    buffer [n] = (short)(temp1 * short.MaxValue);
                }
                n2++;
            }
        }
```

SinMath does this Math.PI * Frequency / 44100D somewhere else
but it is still not fast enough 
any ideas ?